# Checking property values in an EasyMock matcher

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, easymock

Imagine, I have an EasyMock test, in which I have following lines:

```
final IRunControl runControl = createMock(IRunControl.class);
runControl.setSomething(isA(ISomething.class));
EasyMock.expectLastCall().once();
```

`ISomething` looks like this:

```
interface ISomething
{
    int getValue1();

    String getValue2();
}
```

Is it possible to make `runControl.setSomething(isA(ISomething.class))` check the values of properies?

I. e. do something like

```
runControl.setSomething(
    and(
        isA(ISomething.class),
        and(propertyValue("value1", 123), propertyValue("value2", "expectedValue2")))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is to use [Capture](http://easymock.org/api/org/easymock/Capture.html).

An example:

```
    // setup: data
    ISomething fooSomething = ISomethingImpl(5, "bar"); 

    // setup: expectations
    Capture<ISomething> capturedISomething = new Capture<ISomething>();
    mockCollaborator.setSomething(capture(capturedISomething));

    // exercise
    replay(mockCollaborator);
    sut.dooWhateverThatInvokesTheCollaboratorSetter(fooSomething);

    // verify
    verify(mockCollaborator);
    assertEquals(5, capturedISomething.getValue().getValue1());
    assertEquals("bar", capturedISomething.getValue().getValue2());
```